# cmake - osx/mac - openssl brew

Tags: macos, openssl, cmake, homebrew

I am using the following cmake commands

```
# Search OpenSSL
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(OPENSSL REQUIRED openssl)

if( OPENSSL_FOUND )

    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(STATUS "Using OpenSSL ${OPENSSL_VERSION}")
else()
    # Error; with REQUIRED, pkg_search_module() will throw an error by it's own
endif()
```

it works on Linux and on Mac, but on Mac it uses the osx-shipped libssl - which throws a a lot of deprecation warnings e.g. `'SSL_library_init' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.7"`

using `brew` I already installed a newer - openssl-offical - libssl - how can I tell the `pkg_search_module` in cmake to find and use the brew version?

Comment: You could use `FIND_PACKAGE(OpenSSL)` and specify the location of your OpenSSL installation like it is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16249265/678093

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok got it working :)

```
brew upgrade openssl
brew link --force openssl
pkg-config --modversion openssl
#1.0.2
```

removed the cmake build folder and rerun the `cmake ..` and the above macro now finds the 1.0.2 libssl :)

Comment: This does not work anymore: Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure, deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.

Comment: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"` before `pkg-config --modversion openssl` in order for it to work

Answer (score 18):

As of late 2016 this works for me:

In CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(openssl REQUIRED)
```

Run cmake like this:

```
cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl .
```

Comment: To be version independent the following works:
`-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

Comment: Just doing  `find_package(openssl REQUIRED)` works on cmake 3.10. Had issues on 3.16, so switched back to 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan is right.  The MacOS system open ssl is considered insecure.  Here is what works for me

1. Install or upgrade openssl via brew
2. Add these to your CMakefile.  Instead of hard coding you might choose to use a command line parameter or environment variable

   include_directories(BEFORE /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p/include)
   find_library(OPENSSL_LIB 
                   ssl
                   PATHS /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p/lib
                   NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
   find_library(CRYPTO_LIB
                   crypto
                   PATHS /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p/lib
                   NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

To find the OpenSSL directory use the following command:

```
brew list openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue is [a bug in CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16885) -- it does not use alternate `pkg-config` paths correctly.

According to the merge request attached to the bug, the fix should be in cmake 3.17.0 (to be released in Feb 2020).

Otherwise, use [this work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356903/6997562). Hard coding it in your `CMakeLists.txt` will make things bad for people who use MacPorts instead of Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2021 this works for me:

change to

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.2)
```

and

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have install openssl of specify version by brew, let's say, openssl@1.1, then you can use

```sh
brew info openssl@1.1
```

and it will tell you all you need to do:

```
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```