# How can I install Net::SSLeay with perlbrew in macOS Catalina?

Tags: perl, cassandra, openssl, macos-catalina

I am trying to install Net::SSLeay perl package on Mac OSX Catalina using perlbrew cpanm and failing due to openssl related issues.

I tried all of the bellow solutions to no avail:

- [cmake - osx/mac - openssl brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792009/cmake-osx-mac-openssl-brew)
- https://gist.github.com/andyjack/7dd4d7b65d262b2a6e56
- https://medium.com/@deepak.gulati/installing-net-ssleay-on-os-x-el-capitan-446c40cffeba
- https://phillipadsmith.com/2016/03/Installing-Net-SSLeay-on-OS-X-El-Capitan.html
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240589/crypt-ssleay-on-a-macbook
- https://macosx.com/threads/howto-installing-openssl-and-the-ssl-perl-module-net-ssleay-pm.12075/

I have open ssl latest and added the suggested exports to my .zshrc

I added these to .zshrc:

```
# Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: openssl@1.1
# If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"

# For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

# For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

the basic failure is:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7044 on perl 5.030001 built for darwin-2level
Work directory is /Users/<me>
/.cpanm/work/1583739797.88350
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.43
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.6
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching Net::SSLeay () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Net::SSLeay
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CH/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz
Entering Net-SSLeay-1.88
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.34)
Configuring Net-SSLeay-1.88
Running Makefile.PL
Do you want to run external tests?
These tests *will* *fail* if you do not have network connectivity. [n] n
*** Found LibreSSL-2.8.3 installed in /usr
*** Be sure to use the same compiler and options to compile your OpenSSL, perl,
    and Net::SSLeay. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Net::SSLeay
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Test::More 0.60_01 ... Yes (1.302162)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.34)
Checking if you have MIME::Base64 0 ... Yes (3.15)
Building and testing Net-SSLeay-1.88
cp lib/Net/SSLeay.pm blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm (blib/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay)
blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm: some names are not unique when truncated to 8 characters:
 directory blib/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay:
  do_https3.al, do_https2.al, do_https4.al, do_https.al truncate to do_https
  do_httpx3.al, do_httpx2.al, do_httpx4.al truncate to do_httpx
  get_https.al, get_https3.al, get_https4.al, get_http.al, get_http3.al, get_http4.al, get_httpx.al, get_httpx3.al, get_httpx4.al truncate to get_http
  head_https.al, head_https3.al, head_https4.al, head_http.al, head_http3.al, head_http4.al, head_httpx.al, head_httpx3.al, head_httpx4.al truncate to head_htt
  post_https.al, post_https3.al, post_https4.al, post_http.al, post_http3.al, post_http4.al, post_httpx.al, post_httpx3.al, post_httpx4.al truncate to post_htt
  put_https.al, put_https3.al, put_https4.al, put_http.al, put_http3.al, put_http4.al, put_httpx.al, put_httpx3.al, put_httpx4.al truncate to put_http
  ssl_read_all.al, ssl_read_until.al, ssl_read_CRLF.al truncate to ssl_read
  ssl_write_all.al, ssl_write_CRLF.al truncate to ssl_writ
  tcp_read_all.al, tcp_read_until.al, tcp_read_CRLF.al truncate to tcp_read
  tcp_write_all.al, tcp_write_CRLF.al truncate to tcp_writ
cp lib/Net/SSLeay/Handle.pm blib/lib/Net/SSLeay/Handle.pm
cp lib/Net/SSLeay.pod blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod
Running Mkbootstrap for SSLeay ()
chmod 644 "SSLeay.bs"
"/Users/<me>
/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- SSLeay.bs blib/arch/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.bs 644
"/Users/<me>
/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perl" "/Users/<me>
/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/Users/<me>
/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/Users/<me>
/.cpanm/work/1583739797.88350/Net-SSLeay-1.88/typemap'  SSLeay.xs > SSLeay.xsc
mv SSLeay.xsc SSLeay.c
cc -c   -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.88\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.88\"  "-I/Users/<me>
/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/darwin-2level/CORE"   SSLeay.c
SSLeay.xs:163:10: fatal error: 'openssl/err.h' file not found
#include <openssl/err.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [SSLeay.o] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing Net::SSLeay failed. See /Users/<me>
/.cpanm/work/1583739797.88350/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Comment: Did you follow the [OS X directions from Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/source/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88/README.OSX)? What exports did you add .zshrc? What's the output when you try to install it?

Comment: @briandfoy I added what you asked for (for the basic case) and will investigate your link

Comment: @briandfoy I have openssl installed but the cpanm installation doesn't recognise it. If I use the instructions in the link I am likely to muck the brew instalment and create other problems. since I use these libraries in docker images and this is only for intellisene in the IDE I will forgo the risk.

Comment: `fatal error: 'openssl/err.h' file not found` : Can you check if there is a file `openssl/err.h` in `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes i do (wielder) ➜  ~ ls -la /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include/openssl | grep -w err.h
-rw-r--r--    1 <me>  staff   11269 Sep 10 16:13 err.h
(wielder) ➜  ~

Comment: @HåkonHægland how do I add it to the path?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after much fiddling I found this post:
[OSX Catalina work around](https://gist.github.com/andyjack/7dd4d7b65d262b2a6e56)

I uninstalled latest perlversion:

```
perlbrew uninstall perl-5.30.1
```

Then I ran this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo "$0 is running from: $DIR"

# make this file's location working dir
cd "$(dirname "$0")"


v='perl-5.30.1'

perl_versions=$(perlbrew list)

echo "perl_versions $perl_versions"

if [[ "$perl_versions" == *"$v"* ]]; then
    echo "$v is installed in perlbrew."
else
    echo "$v is not!!! installed in perlbrew.  installing ...."
    perlbrew install perl-5.30.1 --notest --force
fi


current_perl_version=$(which perl)

echo "current_perl_version: $current_perl_version"

if [[ "$current_perl_version" == *"$v"* ]]; then
    echo "$v is current version."
else
    echo "$v is not current version."
    perlbrew switch $v
fi


cpanm  install --force Test::Block
cpanm  install Try::Tiny
cpanm  install YAML
cpanm  install YAML::XS
cpanm  install JSON
cpanm  install JSON::MaybeXS
cpanm  install HTTP::Request
cpanm  install HTTP::Response
cpanm  install HTTP::Daemon

cpanm  install GD::Simple
cpanm  install GD::Graph
cpanm  install Data::HexDump::Range
cpanm  install Proc::Daemon
cpanm  install Test::Block
cpanm  install Text::Colorizer
cpanm  install Gzip::Faster

cpanm  install IO::Socket::INET6

#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
#export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
#export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

cpanm install DBI

#cpanm  install Net::SSLeay
OPENSSL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 cpanm --interactive --verbose --force Net::SSLeay


cpanm install --force Cassandra::Client

cpanm install DBD::Cassandra
#cpanm install https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/T/TV/TVDW/Cassandra-Client-0.16.tar.gz

cpanm  install Proc::ProcessTable
cpanm  install Kafka::Connection
```

During the Net::SSLeay installation I was prompted for manual confirmation for tests dependant on network connectivity and answered y. If anyone knows auto-approve in perlbrew please post a comment, A quick scower of perlbrew -h wasn't informative as to auto approve options at first glance.

Comment: setting OPENSSL_PREFIX is exactly what the [Net::SSLeay OS X README](https://metacpan.org/source/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88/README.OSX) instructions said to do. That's something I have set in my bash profile.

Comment: @briandfoy I wonder if it doesn't shadow the path for other programs

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on macOS Catalina (note my shell is `bash` and not the default `zsh`):

```
brew install openssl
\curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

After perlbrew is installed, edit `~/.bash_profile` :

```
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

Then save, and execute

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ perlbrew install-cpanm
$ perlbrew install perl-5.30.1 --notest
$ perlbrew switch perl-5.30.1
$ cpanm Net::SSLeay
--> Working on Net::SSLeay
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CH/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Net-SSLeay-1.88 ... OK
Building and testing Net-SSLeay-1.88 ... OK
Successfully installed Net-SSLeay-1.88
1 distribution installed
```

So my guess would be that the issue is related to `zsh`, since I used `bash` and you used `zsh`.

Comment: I tried moving it to bashrc it appears in shell env variable but it failed

Comment: I am removing perl version from perlbrew and restarting the installation hopefully it will work and I will indorse

Comment: Re installing perl didn't help